# How to store data in database columns accordingly within a loop

Tags: java, jsp, vector, db2

I'm having a list of items in vector table but the items size might have different size, how can i store these items in database column accordingly based on the items number.  Example: i have list item with `[apple,red,24]` i want to store this item accordingly in database column `value1= apple`, `value2=red`,`value3=24` by using looping ? below are the current sample code and database columns.

### example of database design

VALUE1  | VALUE2   | VALUE3   |VALUE4    | VALUE5

### jsp file

```
    for(int i =0; i <2; i++)
        {

            Vector vTables = (Vector)session.getAttribute("SES_VALUE"+i); 
            //first vector list [[apple,red,5],[orange,orange,3]]
            //second vector list [[apple,red,5,big],[orange,orange,4,small]]

                for(int k = 0; k < vTables.size(); k++) 
                { 

                    Vector vTemp2           = (Vector) vTables.elementAt(i); 
                   //first loop vTemp2 list [[apple,red,5],[orange,orange,3]] 

                        DB_BS.makeConnection();
                        iRowAffected = DB_BS.insert_table_value(vTemp2);
                        DB_BS.takeDown();   
                }

        }
```

### java file --im stuck on this part

```
public int insert_table_value(Vector vtTable)throws Exception 
{
    //vtTable item will be  [[apple,red,5],[orange,orange,3]] 

    for(int k = 1; k <= vtTable.size(); k++) 
    { 
        //in this sValue will get each items from the vtTable
        String sValue           = (String) vtTable.elementAt(k); 

       //how to write an sql query at here??  
       //what i plan to do is, if sValue have 3 item, it will store the value in database per columns accodingly
        String myQuery = "INSERT INTO TB_BS_VALUE ( ) VALUES ( )"; 

        pstmt2 = new PreparedStatementLogable(myConn, myQuery);
        pstmt2.setString(k, sValue);

        myQuery = pstmt2.toString();
        pstmt = myConn.prepareStatement(myQuery);
        RowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();

        if (RowsAffected > 0) 
            insertSQLLog("SQL", myQuery, "", "", "", "");
    }
    return RowsAffected;
}
```

Comment: This (numerated value columns) is usually a poor design.  Why was your db setup this way?  What are you actually trying to do with this data?  Generally speaking, you want separate columns for logically separate values, but this design precludes that (ie, `value3 = 24` is rather meaningless on its own).  You're going to have problems searching for or updating values in this design.  Data integrity is going to be a problem.  You probably want one or more other tables (although storing blob data might be appropriate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String sValue is a single String, so first thing should be to split it up (by "," according to your comment)

```
String[] result = sValue.split(",");
```

then you could do

```
String columns = "";
String values = "";

for (int i = 0; i <= result.size(); i++) {
   columns += "VALUE" + (i+1) +",";
   values+="?,";
}

// get rid of trailing ,
columns = b.replace(columns.lastIndexOf(","), columns.lastIndexOf(",") + 1,""); 
values = b.replace(values.lastIndexOf(","), values.lastIndexOf(",") + 1,"");

String myQuery = "INSERT INTO TB_BS_VALUE ("+columns+") VALUES ("+values+")"; 

pstmt = new PreparedStatementLogable(myConn, myQuery);

for (int i = 0; i <= result.size(); i++) {
    pstmt.setString(i, result[i]);
}
```

The two for-loops could possible be collapsed into one, not sure about that thought, and can't try it out atm.

Note that

```
RowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

should not compile, should propably be

```
int rowsAffected = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```